# Plot streamplot for two stability point for Jacobian

Tags: plotting, webmathematica, mathematica-online, stability

I have two points (0,0) and (5,-5). How can I plot the stability phase diagram for these two points in a single `StreamPlot` in *Mathematica* by showing those points with dots?

Comment: What are the equations describing the system you want to plot?

Comment: Are these points fix points? If so, a stream plot of the linearized equations about those points will show you if the you have a sink, a source, a saddle, spiral source/sink,...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without your function we can't give a full answer, but this should suffice:

```
StreamPlot[{-1 - x^2 + y, 1 + x - y^2},
 {x, -6, 6}, {y, -6, 6},
 Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[0.03], Point[{0, 0}], Point[{-5, 5}]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. It helps.